# Drupal Navigation Conundrum

Tags: drupal, menu

I'm attempting to set up navigation withing a Drupal site and am having a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to have a series of pages that each have a set number of sub-pages. These pages will need to link to one another. All pages will contain similar content. For instance:

Page 1 will have sub-pages a, b, c, d, e, and f all with content related to the topic of page 1
Page 2 will have sub-pages a, b, c, d, e, and f with content related to the topic of page 2

I'd like these links to appear in a horizontal nav bar on each page.

Is it possible to accomplish this using the book module? I've also read some information about the taxonomy menu module that sounds promising, but I'm not really sure how that would work.

What route should I look into? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

Oh, there are so many ways of creating this, it can easily be overwhelming, and the right one to choose depends on a lot of factors -- how the nodes will be created and maintained, level of technical skill, need for re-use, need for flexibility, number of items involved, etc. Both of the methods you mention are possible. There's also the node_hierarchy module.

You can also just create regular nodes, and use the regular menu system to create the hierarchy. Then use menu_block to split out the parts of the menu that you want to display separately, and place them in whatever region you want. A little CSS and you've got a horizontal nav bar....

Answer (score 1):

As sprugman said (+1), there are many ways to do it, and we need more details to make a proper suggestion.

That said, my immediate reaction would be [CCK modules](http://drupal.org/project/cck) nodereference fields - they allow you to reference (one or multiple) nodes from within other nodes. How these references are displayed is widely configurable, but they get displayed as links pretty much by default, so turning them into a nav bar should be pretty straight forward. If you are new to CCK, [this step by step instruction](http://pras.net.np/blogs/guide-cck-nodereference) might be helpful, but googling for 'Drupal CCK nodereference' should turn up quite some results.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.

Basically, the product my organization offers is fairly complex, and to sufficiently describe the products, each product will have a set of 7 pages—each describing costs, specs, etc.

Each product will have the exact same 7 pages that are linked to through a horizontal nav on each page. I'd like to somehow make this easy to accomplish while retaining the text for each link as "About" "Specs" "Fees" etc...

I hope that's helpful.... Thanks for any additional input!